# How to explicitly pass user data to passport.authenticate

Tags: express, socket.io, polymer, passport.js, passport-local

I'm making a webapp that uses Socket.io to pass information between the server and the client, one example being login information. The documentation for passport.authenticate says to use it like so:

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: '/login' }));
```

However, my webapp is using Polymer client-side routing, so the only route my index.js has is this:

```
app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile('./public/index.html', {root: '.'});
});
```

Instead, I'd like to do something like this:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('login', function(data){
        passport.authenticate('local', data);
    });
});
```

However, this doesn't work as the authenticate function doesn't even get called right now. Is there a way to make passport work in such a scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You can define your custom callback with `passport.authenticate()`. I have given a example below, you might wanna try that. Go [here](http://passportjs.org/docs) for more info.

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('login', function(data){
        var req = {}
        req.body = data 
        passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
           if (err) { 
               socket.emit('login', { success: false });
           }
           if (!user) { 
               socket.emit('login', { success: false }); 
           }
           // Set session
           req.logIn(user, function(err) {
               if (err) { 
                   socket.emit('login', { success: false });
               }
               socket.emit('login', { success: true });
           });
    });
});
```

**Update:** Problem with previous code was, when using custom callbacks in passport authenticate it uses `req` object from the closure, which in this case was undefined as it was not in the router. I think, now that you can provide enough authentication data through req.body it should work.

Comment: The above example , will give undefined error for req.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below .
In your routes define and require the socket module, so you have access to use it in routes.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var router = express.Router();
var passport = require('passport');

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('login', function(data){
       // call the routes 
       router.post('/login', function(request, response, next) {
          passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
             if (err) {
              // return next(err);
              socket.emit('loginResult', { success: false });
             }
            if (!user) {
               var message = "Invalid credentials";
               socket.emit('loginResult', { success: false , message: message});
            }
            request.logIn(user, function (err) {
            if (err) {
               socket.emit('loginResult', { success: false });
            }
           // if want to save user in session
            request.session.user = user;
            // after success code
           socket.emit('loginResult', { success: true , user : user});
         });
       })(request, response, next);
     });
   });
});
```

Hope this helps.